# Gmail has gone completely crazy

Tags: gmail, bugs

Gmail went completely crazy, I don't know what to do.

When I open it I get the inbox, but the app is almost unresponsive: whatever I do, be it opening the menu, scrolling or opening a message, it starts to do it (the menu starts opening, the message gets highlighted) but after a fraction of a second it flashes and gets back to the inbox itself as if nothing happened.

I still receive new mail notifications in the top bar, but clicking them prompts the inbox anyway, with the same problems.

Even after managing to evade the application using the home button, sometimes it pops up again, going crazy even if I don't touch it (flashing repeatedly the inbox, doing a "left to right" slide-like effect), and the whole system can be unresponsive for a while.

Other applications, including google ones (calendar, docs, contacts), appear to have no problems.

Phone is a Nexus S, was running android 2.3.4, I upgraded to 2.3.6 and upgraded the gmail app too, but nothing changed.

Doing a "clear data" prompts the "mails will appear shortly" screen, and there the menu works, but as soon as I receive the emails, it goes crazy again.

I'm clueless, what could I do?

Comment: apparently I'm not the only one with this problem: http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/topic/mobile/WbS58lDO2VY/discussion

Comment: That's seriously weird. I had some problems with Gmail too recently but nothing like this. One poster there mentioned changing the account password hlped, did you try that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/Cw1AKdxpj7c/discussion) discussion.

Is your problem same as the one discussed here? If so, Google is working on a fix.

Comment: This thread apparently is more up-to-date than the one I linked, thanks.